# Possible modification of nested for loop

Tags: shell, command-line

I am a newbie, and am trying to modify the code below so that it takes less time to run. (Right now it takes ages.)   Please help or give any suggestions, if possible.  Thank you beforehand.

```
#!/bin/sh
for pheno in `cat /wrk/abc/composition/results/list.txt`; do
  header=`head -1 /wrk/abc/composition/results/"$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out`
  echo "pheno $header" > results.txt
  for pheno in `cat /wrk/abc/composition/results/list.txt`; do
    awk -v p="$pheno" \
        'NR == FNR{a[$1]; next}($3) in a{print p, $0}' \
        list.txt \
        /wrk/abc/composition/results/"$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out \ 
        >>  results.txt
  done
done
```

Comment: Explain what you want, show input and output files, and first check the results when you only use the awk command.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming *list.txt* is line separated, here's the same code simplified, with no useless `cat`s, (the `for` loops where swapped for `while read`s), and using `cd` to reduce unreadable long paths, followed by some notes.  It should be only a little faster, and work the *same* as before, such as it was:

```
cd /wrk/abc/composition/results/
while read pheno ; do
    { echo -n pheno; head -1 "$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out ; } \
       > results.txt
    while read pheno ; do
        awk -v p="$pheno" \
            'NR == FNR{a[$1]; next}($3) in a{print p, $0}' \
            list.txt \
            "$pheno"/meta_"$pheno".out \ 
            >>  results.txt
    done < list.txt
done < list.txt
cd -
mv /wrk/abc/composition/results/results.txt ./
```

The most glaring error is that there are two loops, one nested in the other; both use the same variable name (*$pheno*), both input the same file (*list.txt*) -- surprisingly, that sort of code may function correctly, despite being confusing.  But this must cause the slowdown, since the inner loop runs `awk` on that same input file.  So if there were 100 lines in *list.txt*, that file might be read 1,000,000 times.

Then there's *results.txt*, which the inner loop appends data to, and the outer loop *overwrites* every cycle.  *results.txt* therefore winds up being filled with only the data from the very last cycle.

Comment: Thank you soo much! i will try to digest your code :)

Comment: Sorry, when i run your code for only one variable in a list.txt it returns - awk: (FILENAME=meta_var_pros.out FNR=10453692) fatal: cannot open file ` ' for reading (No such file or directory). Why it could happen? Thank you.

Comment: Is it i need to use cd - somewhere before awk to return to the correct pwd?

Comment: The `cd` was to prevent the code needing unreadible long path names.  The `mv` at the end is to put _results.txt_ in whatever the current directory was, when the script is run.

Comment: @HoHoHo, what's the output of    `head -n 1 /wrk/abc/composition/results/list.txt`?